# Hangman written in python doesnt recognise correct letters guessed :/

Tags: python

So I'm working my first project which hangman written in python every works like the visuals and the incorrect letters. However, It is unable to recognise the correct letter guessed.

```
import random
from hangman_visual import lives_visual_dict
import string

# random word 

with open('random.txt', 'r') as f:
    All_Text = f.read()
    words = list(map(str, All_Text.split()))
WORD2GUESS = random.choice(words).upper()
letters = len(WORD2GUESS)
print("_" * letters)

word_letters = set(WORD2GUESS)
alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
lives = 7
used_letters = set()

# user input side 
while len(word_letters) > 0 and lives > 0:
        # letters used
        # ' '.join(['a', 'b', 'cd']) --> 'a b cd'
        print('You have', lives, 'lives left and you have used these letters: ', ' '.join(used_letters))

        # what current word is (ie W - R D)
        word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-' for letter in WORD2GUESS]
        print(lives_visual_dict[lives])
        print('Current word: ', ' '.join(word_list))

        user_letter = input('Guess a letter: ').upper()
        if user_letter in alphabet - used_letters:
            used_letters.add(user_letter)
            if user_letter in WORD2GUESS:
                used_letters.remove(user_letter)
                print('')

            else:
                lives = lives - 1  # takes away a life if wrong
                print('\nYour letter,', user_letter, 'is not in the word.')

        elif user_letter in used_letters:
            print('\nYou have already used that letter. Guess another letter.')

        else:
            print('\nThat is not a valid letter.')

if lives == 0:
    print(lives_visual_dict[lives])
    print('You died, sorry. The word was', WORD2GUESS)
else:
    print('YAY! You guessed the word', WORD2GUESS, '!!')
```

I've tried this, but it still wont recognise the correct guess.

```
        # what current word is (ie W - R D)
        word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-' for letter in WORD2GUESS]
        print(lives_visual_dict[lives])
        print('Current word: ', ' '.join(word_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is this: When checking if the `user_letter` is in the `WORD2GUESS`, you falsely remove it from `used_letters`, but it has to stay in the set.

Also you are missing some way of escaping the while loop when fully guessing the word. That could be done at the same spot by checking if `used_letters` contain all the letters in `WORD2GUESS`.

Something like this:

```
import random
from hangman_visual import lives_visual_dict
import string

# random word 

with open('random.txt', 'r') as f:
    All_Text = f.read()
    words = list(map(str, All_Text.split()))
WORD2GUESS = random.choice(words).upper()
letters = len(WORD2GUESS)
print("_" * letters)

word_letters = set(WORD2GUESS)
alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
lives = 7
used_letters = set()

# user input side 
while len(word_letters) > 0 and lives > 0:
        # letters used
        # ' '.join(['a', 'b', 'cd']) --> 'a b cd'
        print('You have', lives, 'lives left and you have used these letters: ', ' '.join(used_letters))

        # what current word is (ie W - R D)
        word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-' for letter in WORD2GUESS]
        print(lives_visual_dict[lives])
        print('Current word: ', ' '.join(word_list))

        user_letter = input('Guess a letter: ').upper()
        if user_letter in alphabet - used_letters:
            used_letters.add(user_letter)
            if user_letter in WORD2GUESS:
                print('\nThat is a correct letter.')
                if set(WORD2GUESS).issubset(used_letters):
                    break

            else:
                lives = lives - 1  # takes away a life if wrong
                print('\nYour letter,', user_letter, 'is not in the word.')

        elif user_letter in used_letters:
            print('\nYou have already used that letter. Guess another letter.')

        else:
            print('\nThat is not a valid letter.')

if lives == 0:
    print(lives_visual_dict[lives])
    print('You died, sorry. The word was', WORD2GUESS)
else:
    print('YAY! You guessed the word', WORD2GUESS, '!!')
```

Comment: Damn thank you so much took me a second to realise what you were saying BUT IT WORKED. Appreciate it a lot ;)

Comment: @JunaidKhan Glad I could help :) Would you mind marking the answer as accepted? It helps a lot - Thanks!